# 405 Message, method not allowed with Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have got the following on an API controller:

```
public void UpdateClient(Client client)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
    }
```

And the following on the page:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "api/client/UpdateClient",
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(model.selectedClient()),
            success: function (result) {
                getClients();
                $("#loader").hide();
            },
            failure: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
                $("#loader").hide();
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("An error occurred, please try again.");
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
        });
```

But this gives the error 405 Method Not Allowed, can anyone see where I may have gone wrong?  For reference the url for the api is ok as I use the same api controller for other functions too.

Also the selectedClient() is a Client object received via WebApi so should match perfectly to PUT up again.

Comment: Which webserver are you using? Because in IIS you have to manually enable Put and Delete see http://forums.iis.net/t/1166025.aspx

Comment: IIS Express that comes with VS 2012 Express for Web

Comment: Then see the [How do I enable verbs like PUT/DELETE for my web application?](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq) from the IIS Express FAQ.

Comment: Which verbs do I change on the host file though, there's quite a few

Comment: or one might disable WebDAV publishing from `Control Panel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like these two lines were wrong, I changed them as follows:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
data: "{client: " + ko.toJSON(model.selectedClient()) + "}",
```

And now goes in.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using IIS7 and have WebDav installed, try removing it. 
I was getting the same error only with the PUT verb and it solved the issue

Update: You can read about WebDav here: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-7/what39s-new-for-webdav-and-iis-7

Comment: +1, It solved my problem, but what if we want to have that module also?

Comment: Try adding the following in your web.config file 
`code`<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>

Comment: In my case I also had to add `<handlers><remove name="WebDAV" /></handlers>` to the `system.webServer` section (I'm on IIS8).

Comment: or one might disable `WebDAV` publishing from `Control Panel`.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have [HttpPut] attribute on your UpdateClient action?  Also, do you have a route that takes in the {action} as the routeTemplate?  For example:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

One more thing, try 'application/json' for the content-type in your ajax code instead of 'json'.

Answer (score 1):

Note to future troubleshooters: I got this error when my "Put" controller was unintentionally expecting an additional parameter that wasn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that under project properties, I was using Local IIS instead of IIS Express, and it defaulted to port 80 which blocked DELETE requests. Changing to IIS Express fixed it.