# Dto object update method not updating in Postman

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have a get, create, delete, and update method using automapper and Dtos in an asp.net web api I created, but for some reason I can't get the update method to work in postman. 
I select Put in postman and change values in one of the tables like for instance

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "movieTitle": "Movie 1",
    "genreId": 3,
    "releaseDate": "1977-05-02T00:00:00"
  }
```

to

```
  {
    "id": 3,
    "movieTitle": "Movie 11",
    "genreId": 3,
    "releaseDate": "1977-05-02T00:00:00"
  }
```

But the values never update when I hit send in postman.
I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong since I have the id as the same. All the other methods are working, but not the update method. No exception/error is thrown. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
            [HttpPut]
            public IHttpActionResult UpdateMovie(int id, MovieDto movieDto)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return BadRequest();

                var movieInDb = _context.Movie.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

                if (movieInDb == null)
                    return NotFound();

                Mapper.Map(movieDto, movieInDb);

                _context.SaveChanges();

                return Ok();
            }
```

Whole Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using AutoMapper;
using Vidly1.Dtos;
using Vidly1.Models;

namespace Vidly1.Controllers.Api
{
    public class MoviesController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MoviesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();



        }


        public IEnumerable<MovieDto> getMovies()
        {
            return _context.Movie.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<Movie, MovieDto>);


        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMovie(int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();


            }

            var movie = _context.Movie.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);


            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();

            }

            return Ok(Mapper.Map<Movie, MovieDto>(movie));


        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateMovie(MovieDto movieDto)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();

            }

            var movie = Mapper.Map<MovieDto, Movie>(movieDto);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();

            }

            _context.Movie.Add(movie);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            movieDto.Id = movie.Id;
            return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + movie.Id), movieDto);
        }


        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateMovie(int id, MovieDto movieDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

            var movieInDb = _context.Movie.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (movieInDb == null)
                return NotFound();

            Mapper.Map(movieDto, movieInDb);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }


        [HttpDelete]
        public void DeleteMovie(int id, MovieDto movieDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            }
            var movie = _context.Movie.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

            if (movie == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            }

            _context.Movie.Remove(movie);
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) What does your request look like? 2) Is the action reached? 3) Are the values binding to your method? 3) Have you stepped through with the debugger? What is the final exit path?

Comment: The only message I see is inside Postman when I click send.  The output says {
  "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."
}

Comment: Also I see Status 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Are you using attribute routing or convention-based routing? This is related to how you configured your routes and how you names your actions.

Comment: So now you have an error message to investigate. Here on SO there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807331/405-message-method-not-allowed-with-web-api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718741/405-method-not-allowed-web-api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162825/web-api-put-request-generates-an-http-405-method-not-allowed-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293782/mvc-web-api-405-method-not-allowed among others.